# Handling large text files in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, text, large-files

Hey there! I am needing to read large text files up to 100mb in size. I need to read each line Search for a string and write the results to a log. What would be the best way of doing this? Should I read each line individually and search it then move on to the next one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allocating a string of up to 200mb isn't that much at all these days. Just read it all at once and process it.

Comment: Would this be very efficient? I should have noted it should be as efficient as possible, Is it possible to run 2 threads each reading half of the file at the same time?

Comment: Running on two threads at once helps CPU bound tasks. This one is I/O bound.

Comment: OK, so it would be a better idea to do this while searching the file line by line then when actually reading it?

Comment: If that is indeed your only requirement, searching for a string in the file while counting line numbers, just read it all in a string and call `.IndexOf`. It's hard to get better results than this.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [memory mapped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx) files.